# how to replace UrlReffer from .net to .netCore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am currently working on the conversion of my .NET project to .Net Core. 
I am finding it difficult to replace a few items that are used in the old project to the new one. 
Please help me out with it. 
regards. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For referrer:

```cs
var urlReferrer = HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer;
```

or

```cs
var urlReferrer = new Uri(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
```

for controller and action name:

```cs
var routeData = filterContext.RouteData;
string controller = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
string action = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
```